# (PostgreSQL, Node.js & Discord.js) . Why is my query output showing something completely different than what it is in the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, discord.js

The issue (in more detail): I am new to PostgreSQL and I was running a query in Postbird which just created a table with a bunch of values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE guild_settings (
  mute_role_id bigint,
  guild_id bigint,
  member_role_id bigint,
  mod_log bigint,
  member_log bigint
);
```

I inserted a value as a test into the column `guild_id` in PostBird using the "Query" Feature:

```sql
INSERT INTO guild_settings (guild_id) VALUES (843893421277446185);
```

Now, I come into my code editor and I run the code (in an async function run as a command):

```js
const res = await sql `select * from guild_settings`;
console.log(res)
```

When I run the command above I get this:

```js
[
  {
    mute_role_id: null,
    guild_id: 843893421277446100,
    member_role_id: null,
    mod_log: null,
    member_log: null
  },
  count: 1,
  command: 'SELECT'
]
```

As you may tell, the last 3 digits are different than the one I inputted.

Why is the `guild_id` showing `843893421277446100` when I very clearly made it `843893421277446185`? I deleted the table, went to a different database, I tried everything, but nothing seemed to work. I also scoured the internet for answers but I couldn't find anything.

Code:

```js
sql.begin(async sql => {
            const [res] = await sql`
            select guild_id from guild_settings
            `
            console.log([res])
        }).catch(err => console.log(err + "Something went wrong."))
```

Below are some images below of what the database shows as opposed to what the console shows and the query I made.

[The Insert Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHPoL.png)

[The Database Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bTJx.png)

[The Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T2vR.png)

Comment: Make sure you are using the same database name and server in your NodeJS script as you are viewing/editing in Postbird. I can't see another explanation for this.

Comment: I already tried :/ didn't work. This is probably the first time I've ever had to actually make a question about something I've had an issue with, usually people already ask them but this is the first.... I tried switching databases, creating tables, columns, rows... Nothing worked. What do I do? :(

Comment: I think you will have to show more than one line of code for anyone to help you.

Comment: And tell us what you use to connect to the PostgreSQL server. [`node-postgres`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg)?

Comment: Ill edit the code in, I'm using the postgres npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/postgres

Comment: Do you think I should use the node-postgres package instead of the one im using now? Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while PostgreSQL can store [numbers up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/datatype.html) `(2^63-1)` as a bigint, in JavaScript the [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is 9,007,199,254,740,991 (`2^53-1`). Anything above that number is, well, unsafe and JavaScript has difficulty interpreting it.

In your case the last two digits become zero:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Max safe integer | `9007199254740991` |
| Your integer | `843893421277446185` |
| Your integer becomes | `843893421277446100` |

That's why the Snowflake IDs are [returned as string](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes) in the Discord HTTP API (to prevent integer overflows in some languages).

Your solution would be to either store snowflake IDs as strings or instead of the `postgres` npm package use [`node-postgres`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg). As far as I know it returns the correct value for bigints (as JS also supports this data type now).

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried using the node-postgres package and suddenly it returned the right number and that made no sense at all to me, but now I understand! Thank you :D